# What is it called when English takes a word from another language without changing it?

Tags: etymology

What is it called when English takes a word from another language without changing it?

Examples:

- Fernweh (German)
- Vorfreude (German)
- Eutony (Greek)
- Omniscient (Latin)

Comment: I believe this is called a loan word.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never heard of the first three terms. I wouldn't say they were exactly assimilated into the English language...

Comment: Me neither. Better examples are "kindergarten" and "restaurant".

Comment: I wonder how you define "without changing it". I can only find _eutony_ in English as some holistic therapy, whereas the Greek _ευτώνια_ would translate as "good practice". Note that _eutony_ not only changed from the Greek alphabet, but the ending changed as well. Also, the stress was on the _o_, and is now on the _eu_. A majority of loanwords greatly change their pronunciation, which many would consider a change (the word as used now in English may not even be recognisable in spoken language to a speaker of the original language!)

Comment: @Mari-LouA You may be more familiar with a synonym of the first one which is also taken directly from German: _Wanderlust_. (The second one should be _Vorfreude_; there is no such word as _Vorfredue_ in German or English.)

Comment: Borrowings, as well as loanwords.  See lists from different countries here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_by_country_or_language_of_origin, although many have undergone change.

Answer (score 4):

The most commonly used term for a word borrowed from another language and adopted into English  without change is:

**loanword**

> A word adopted from a foreign language with little or no modification.
>   [-Oxford Dictionary On-line](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/loanword)

On the other hand, words which derive from a common proto-form and share meaning across different languages are called:

**[cognate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cognate)**

> (of a word) having the same linguistic derivation as another (e.g. English father, German Vater, Latin pater)

Comment: Cognates may share a common _ancestral_ form, but their defining feature is not their form (which can be highly divergent), but the fact that they derive historically from a common proto-form. English _two_ and Armenian _yerku_, for example, are cognates that share very little in their current form.

Answer (score 0):

When a word is borrowed from another language verbatim, that is called a

> [loanword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword).

The word is loaned directly into English. Examples are:

> [cafe](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cafe), [kindergarten](https://www.etymonline.com/word/kindergarten), [pundit](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pundit), [tea](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tea)

When a word or phrase is borrowed but pieces are translated using the English native forms, that is called a:

> [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque)

Examples are:

> [flea market = marché aux puces](https://www.etymonline.com/word/flea%20market), [long time no see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_time_no_see) = hao jiu bu jian =  好久不見.

Many semi-educated Latinate words in English, 'decide', 'translate', 'subscribe' are direct loanwords (from Church Latin or via Old French) but may have a calque version e.g 'underwrite' for 'subscribe'.

You may notice that 'calque' follow the orthography of French, and indeed ['calque' is a French word](https://www.etymonline.com/word/calque). And from what was said above a French *loanword*. Interestingly enough, ['loan-word' comes from German 'lehnwort'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/loan-word) which is translated piecewise 'loan word'.

This leads one to the observation that 'loanword' is a calque, and 'calque' is a loanword.